# How to block IDN domain in .htaccess file?

Tags: apache-httpd

How can I block IDN domain in .htaccess file, or just a domain with special/ Internationalized marks? I also want to block URLs from, for example, `.ru` `.de` etc.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*xxx\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

I use this to block sites and subsites. But I want to to block domain which contain special marks like: `ąłść` etc. -- and not ones with xxx.com address -- but all sites with contain special marks. It's call IDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the untested assumption that Apache, internally, does not
explicitly support IDN, but rather passes through any domains that it
sees, you could recognize IDNs by the fact that their Punycode-encoded
version starts with `xn--`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://.*xn--.* [NC]
```

This may need tweaking depending on your exact needs (perhaps you want
to be more or less strict than this).

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, but if i would to block IDN from some country? How to do it?

Comment: How do you define "from some country"? The top-level domain? (Such as `.us`, `.ru`?) Something else? It would be best if you edited your question to add this requirement and clarification.

Comment: I edited my question. And yes i would like block domains like `.ru`, `.us` etc

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru [NC]` i use this, and it works.